# Retrieving UpstreamPathTemplate at runtime Ocelot Gateway

Tags: ocelot

I would like to retrieve the "UpstreamPathTemplate" parameter at run time, to use in my Logs. Does anyone know how to do this, please?

Comment: Have you tried to use middlewares? You can use one of the possible [middlewares](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/middlewareinjection.html) and access the context to look at the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [middleware](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/middlewareinjection.html) in the OcelotPipelineConfiguration and access the route in the context.

Something like that:

```
            {
                //PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware occurs after authorization
                PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
                {
                    var upstreamRoute = ctx.DownstreamReRoute.UpstreamPathTemplate;
                    Log.Information($"{upstreamRoute}");
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
            };
```

Or implement your own ASP.NET middleware, catch all requests and log or whatever you want.