# DownstreamContext of context not found

Tags: ocelot

I'm trying to add a custom middleware to add parameters to the query.

According to some online search, you can do something like this:

```
{
            //PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware occurs after authorization
            PreQueryStringBuilderMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                var upstreamRoute = ctx.DownstreamReRoute.UpstreamPathTemplate;
                Log.Information($"{upstreamRoute}");
                await next.Invoke();
            }
        };
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063703/retrieving-upstreampathtemplate-at-runtime-ocelot-gateway)

But for me it says HttpContext doesn't contain a definition of DownstreamReRoute.
Is there something I am missing or has this been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, turned out this did actually change and in an earlier versions this still works. But it looks like Ocelot is dead anyway from what I read.

Comment: @HadiSamadzad I simply downgraded to an earlier version that still had it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var upstreamRoute = ctx.Items.DownstreamRoute().UpstreamPathTemplate
```

Use above code instead of
`var upstreamRoute = ctx.DownstreamReRoute.UpstreamPathTemplate;`

Such change was done between 15.0.6 and 16.0.0 Ocelot versions.
For details you can check them on github: https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/compare/15.0.6...16.0.0